# Are comparators essential in a negative feedback model, cybernetic system?

Tags: control, comparator, system

Since there are no cybernetics.stackexchange, I thought it would be meaningful to ask this to people who would possibly understand systems theory and cybernetics.

Can there be a system, a negative feedback model, without a comparator unit in the model? Or is it essential to auto-optimization of the system (autonomicity)?

I imagined a loop like this:

Primer input -> Sensor -> output -> Actuator/Transducer -> feedback -> Sensor...

And if I can model a system like this what would it be called? In homeostasis in biology there are comparators working but can I name this model as a homeostatic model? I want to make a directly, deterministically and dinamically self-regulating system where the comparison process you might say is inherent to the whole system and not reduced to one unit. Where there is no pre-educated comparison making unit.

I'm not sure if this is making any sense to you.
Also, how could I model such a system mathematically (in transfer functions etc.)?

Thanks already.

Comment: Sounds like you are speaking of a classical control loop. The basic one is PID controller https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller , and the discipline you are looking for is *control theory*.

Comment: You haven't drawn a loop.  Perhaps your question would be more clear if you did.  Feedback does imply a comparison, against a constant if nothing else.

Comment: @TimWescott Well, it's more like subtraction, unless it is an on-off controller.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "Cybernetics" is a kinda-sorta synonym for "control theory", in that if you made a Venn diagram there'd be a lot of overlap between the two, but it wouldn't be complete.

Comment: @TimWescott I imagined that it is an archaic term for it, but looked up in Wikipedia and it appears to be a very broad term

Comment: Necessary? In a short answer. YES. regulated control is not possible with feedback. How? study bioengineering to learn the transfer functions for organs, study biochemistry, microbiology and all other medical specialties for the rest

Answer (score 1):

Homeostasis is a very broad system of negative feedback loops that sense, control and compare with a normal range to balance all the functions with priority given as required. There are possibly millions or billions of functions involved in homeostasis that we take for granted with autonomously use our bodies to produce the right pharmaceutical to the right place at the right time or energize muscles to sustain life or regulate hormones or chemical balances to assist in these functions.

Our brains are massively parallel chemical analog computers, albeit "slow" in comparison to digital ones which can only one instruction per cycle per CPU.  Most of these massively parallel processes are autonomous which require no conscious awareness or intervention.

Some of these parameters, processes,  sensors and organs are tested by bloodworks, O2 concentration and hundreds of other medical scanning tools with professional expertise. The field of acupuncture stimulates these sensors on meridians to trigger a reaction to promote healing in different areas, not necessary at the senor site.

Exercise produces a response to promote healing and gradually strengthening and make more elastic our connective tissues and muscles attached.

Each parameter may respond with many sensors for pinpoint location and redundancy. The sensor and controller may be combined in a short loop or communicated by nerve channels or hormone secretion or other chemical channels of plasma, blood, all inputs and output orifices.

The parameters may follow the nerve pathways, hormone, plasma, blood, air or chemical pathways to the control site.  Autonomous controls are handled by one or many various organs. Critical organs are duplicated where possible.

Feedback may be defined as a transfer function or a cycle response in time or frequency.

- For example; there exists a  transfer function for fluid intake, kidney absorption, blood volume control, heart rate, with many specific biological functions until pressure sensors indicate waste elimination is required.

The control response combines many inputs to many outputs with different sensitivities of integral, proportional, and differential and double differential rate of changes in order to coordinate intentional minimize the error within the normal range as required to sustain life and repair/replace wounded or dead cells determined by our DNA/RNA and the response duration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRBliP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This feedback loop must occur even if the mechanism is unknown.

Other fun facts

The CNS, Central Nervous system includes; the spinal cord and the brain.
The PNS, Peripheral Nervous System includes; sensory and motor divisions

A nerve impulse of up 100 millivolts occurs across the axon’s membrane which travel by daisy-chain reactions up to 100 cm/ms along the synaptic nerves each insulated by a Myelin shield.  It has input trigger level to function.

The Thalamus part of the brain is a major message router for directing input/output signals from source to endpoints.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I studied biochemistry and biological feedback loops to understand the "control" more as well. But I still don't understand why a comparison making unit is necessary in a feedback loop. For example, in reactors there are passive safety features, which are abolishing the presence of an electronic/electrical comparator, when the reactor gets too hot these systems work and cools down the reactor, without the need for any intelligent, comparison making unit. Can't this be implemented in a more dynamic model to achieve a passive control over the system w/o a comparator unit?

Comment: There must be some regulated bias force that reacts to the product of sensor-reactive loop or product to remain constant within constraints as the nonlinear behavior is the integrated controller to the environmental regulation with the reactor , even if no external communication is involved

Comment: There must be some regulated bias force that reacts to the product of sensor-reactive loop or product to remain constant within constraints as the nonlinear behavior is the integrated controller to the environmental regulation with the reactor , even if no external communication is involved.

Comment: A lightbulb powered by a weak current and external thermal forces are an example of nonlinear resistance and ambient thermal rise that regulates somewhat  so the resistance increases fast as it heats up until equilibrium. The  controller is the inherent non-linear behavior  where an incremental external force of ambient temperature rise results in the filament resistance increasing to produce less heat. So the controller is the non-linear transfer function with a bias force current with thermal resistance and has negative feedback from external heat.  according to its sensitivity gain constant

Comment: We might  call the lightbulb open loop but the air thermal resistance is the feedback mechanism. For biological equilibrium the feedback might be  a local chemical reaction or   an electrical potential gradient between electrochemical processes so the communication channel is not the typical ones I mentioned but self-contained